# search form ugly alignment if font-sizes of type=text and type=submit are different

Tags: html, forms, css

what I want is:

- text type and submit type inputs will be side by side with same
  height
- font-sizes will be different (submit's font-size 12, other's will be
  16px.)
- text will aligned vertically middle in both inputs

I tried several combinations with `height`, `line-height` also in below CSS however I couldn't achieve.

how can I achieve my requirements with CSS?

```css
    .input, .submit{margin:0;padding:0;border:1px solid #000;}
 .submit{font-size:12px;}
 .input{font-size:16px;}
```

```html
 <form action="#" method="post">
  <input class="input" type="text" name="search"><input class="submit" type="submit" value="SEARCH">
 </form>
```

Comment: Is this what you want https://jsfiddle.net/2y35euv2/

Comment: Their height is not same, difference is about 1 or 2 px . Actually i tried padding top bottom 2px also but height is still different :(

Comment: then you need `line-height`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `height`, `box-sizing` and `vertical-align` together

```css
.input, .submit
{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:1px solid #000;
  /*added*/
  height:25px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.submit{font-size:12px;}
.input{font-size:16px;}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
<input class="input" type="text" name="search">
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="SEARCH">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `line-height` and `vertical-align`:

```css
.input,
.submit {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  line-height:30px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.submit {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.input {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
  <input class="input" type="text" name="search">
  <input class="submit" type="submit" value="SEARCH">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
input{
  display:inline-block;
  line-height:20px;
}
.input, .submit{margin:0;padding:0;border:1px solid #000;}
.submit{font-size:12px;
vertical-align:middle;padding:0px 5px;}
.input{font-size:16px;
vertical-align:middle;}
```

```html
 <form action="#" method="post">
  <input class="input" type="text" name="search"><input class="submit" type="submit" value="SEARCH">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, that normal input have border outside its width and height, and submit input inside.

The sollution is to use **box-sizing: border-box;** for both inputs.

Answer (score -1):

Height/Line-height seems to work although I would add `box-sizing` for compatability purposes.

```css
.input,
.submit {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.submit {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.input {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
  <input class="input" type="text" name="search">
  <input class="submit" type="submit" value="SEARCH">
</form>
```